# How to disable a RibbonGroup of UltraToolBarsManager in c#

Tags: c#, infragistics

I want to disable all tools of a RibbonGroup of my UltraToolBarsManager in click event handler of a button.I know i could use the following code

```
toolBarsManager1.Tools["tool1"].SharedProps.Enabled = 
toolBarsManager1.Tools["tool2"].SharedProps.Enabled = 
toolBarsManager1.Tools["tool3"].SharedProps.Enabled = false;
```

But i want to know if there is a way to set the Enabled property of the **RibbonGroup**, instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  foreach(ToolBase tool in ultraToolbarsManager1.Ribbon.Tabs[TabKey].Groups[RibonGroupKey].Tools)

            {

                tool.SharedProps.Enabled = enable;

            }
```

Comment: Hi irsog and Thanks a lot.It is my answer(Ribbon.Tabs[TabKey].Groups[RibbonGroupKey]). I could not find a way to access to RibbonGroups.